# UItesting Xcode 7 - accessibility issue

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I have added 'Home' title to the navigation item for the sake of accessibility, but it's still treated as a UIPageView

[image]

UI Test Activity: 
    Assertion Failure: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("UIPageView")") is not equal to ("Optional("Home")") -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not an accessibility issue with Xcode, I just selected the wrong controller (I'm using a UIPageViewController for navigation purposes), sorry for wasting your time ;P.